# Toggle checkbox background-color using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap Tree to create a nested checkbox list(http://jhfrench.github.io/bootstrap-tree/docs/example.html), however, I want to make the checked item highlighted, as well as have the children highlighted when the parent is selected. I've got it kind of working, but now when the parent is selected, the background-color on the individual child won't toggle when unchecked. i.e. it only toggles when its parent is not selected. 
See jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/tqku87ym/7/

```
$(function checkbox() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).siblings('ul')
            .find("input[type='checkbox']")
            .prop('checked', this.checked);

        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass("highlight");

    });
});
```

Comment: The background of the parent is showing through the child, so you'd need to override that by applying a style to the child to negate the parent being highlighted. *Background properties are not inherited, but the parent box's background will shine through by default because of the initial 'transparent' value on 'background-color'.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your code in a new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pjrzbbea/.

I've introduced a separated highlight class for the children, which also has a background color overlapping the parent's background color. The JS part now also removes the highlight class from the child elements, if the parent element gets highlighted - so the children get resetted correctly.

```
    $(function checkbox() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var highlightChildClass = 'highlightChild';

        $(this).siblings('ul')
            .find('li')
            .removeClass(highlightChildClass)
            .find("input[type='checkbox']")
            .prop('checked', this.checked);

        var highlightClass = 'highlight';

        if ($(this).closest('ul[role="group"]').length > 0) {
            highlightClass = highlightChildClass;
        } 

        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass(highlightClass);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The only answer that works the way it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't toggle the class if the way to change the background can come from multiple sources.  When you change the parent, you'll have to clean the children.  Here is the sample code modified.  https://jsfiddle.net/wgpahro4/

```
$(function checkbox() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('ul')
        .find("input[type='checkbox']")
        .prop('checked', this.checked);

    //ADDED CODE STARTS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!
    //Clean up children
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("parent_li")){
        if(!this.checked){
           $(this).siblings("ul").find("li").removeClass("highlight");
        }
    }
    //ADDED CODE ENDS HERE!!!!!  

    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass("highlight");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each child checkbox to highlight while the parent checkbox can still override, something like this will work:

```
$(function checkbox() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {

        if ($(this).siblings('ul').length > 0) {
            var children = $(this).siblings('ul').find('input');
            children.prop('checked', this.checked).change();
        }
        else {
            var item = $(this).parent('li');
            this.checked ? item.addClass('highlight') : item.removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fine, but what if I want the parent to be highlighted to o, along with its children?

Comment: Just add this `$(this).parent('li').toggleClass('highlight')` inside the first condition. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bh1pnye6/1/

Comment: If you want to highlight *just* the line, then toggle the class on a <span> that wraps them instead of the while <li>